# Visual Studio puts blank line at the beginning of a new class, even though there is none in the class template

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is how the class template looks:

[image]

And this is how newly created class looks like:

[image]

As you can see, Visual Studio adds a blank line every time I create a new class. Does anybody know why?

*Additional info:*

If I import any usings while coding, it will put it **below** the blank line. I have to delete the blank line every time manually because it serves completely no purpose.

I tried to open the template with Notepad, Notepad++ and Visual Studio itself and there is no blank line there. Also I'm sure I'm editing the correct file because previously it generated all the default usings, which are now gone.

Answer (score -2):

You could solve this problem by steps (going to **Tools**->Select **Options...**->Click **Text Editor**->Select **CodeLens** under **All Language**s->Uncheck **Enable CodeLens** ->Click **OK**) to uncheck Enable CodeLens.

As the picture shows:
[image]
The result before modifying the settings is shown below:

[image]

The result after modifying the settings is shown below:

[image]

Comment: I think the author speak about the very first line, before namespace ^^

Comment: @novaXire yes. CodeLens is very useful for me, it's the blank line that bothers me.